# Database for SonarQube.. MYSQL or Oracle? Same server or external

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

As my team is planning to install SonarQube on a central platform where it will be used by projects across organization please suggest which database is recommended for handling multiple projects in Sonarqube MYSQL or Oracle ?

Also, does it matter if the db is installed on the same server on which SOnarQube will be installed (considering RHEL platform) in terms of performance or should it be recommended to use external DB with SonarQube .

Comment: This question is highly opinion based. However, most SonarQube developers I know use postgres, which seems to be both stable and scalable. If you can only choose between MySQL and Oracle, I'd choose Oracle.

Comment: Thanks @slartidan for your response. Can you also please provide your thoughts on whether its good to have DB installed on the same server where SonarQube web will be installed or on a dedicated server?

Comment: db should be installed on dedicated server (not with sonarqube)